# NameError: name 'Dict' is not defined

Tags: python, python-typing

```py
def loss_metric_curve_plot(model_results:Dict[str,List[float]]):
    train_loss = model_results["train_loss"]
    valid_loss = model_results["valid_loss"]

    train_accuracy = [float(value) for value in model_results["train_accuracy"]]
    valid_accuracy = [float(value) for value in model_results["valid_accuracy"]]

    fig,axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 2, figsize = (10,4))
    axes = axes.flat

    axes[0].plot(train_loss, color = "red", label = "Train")
    axes[0].plot(valid_loss, color = "blue", label = "Valid")
    axes[0].set_title("CrossEntropyLoss", fontsize = 12, fontweight = "bold", color = "black")
    axes[0].set_xlabel("Epochs", fontsize = 10, fontweight = "bold", color = "black")
    axes[0].set_ylabel("Loss", fontsize = 10, fontweight = "bold", color = "black")
    axes[0].legend()

    axes[1].plot(train_accuracy, color = "red", label = "Train")
    axes[1].plot(valid_accuracy, color = "blue", label = "Valid")
    axes[1].set_title("Metric of performance: Accuracy", fontsize = 12, fontweight = "bold", color = "black")
    axes[1].set_xlabel("Epochs", fontsize = 10, fontweight = "bold", color = "black")
    axes[1].set_ylabel("Score", fontsize = 10, fontweight = "bold", color = "black")
    axes[1].legend()

    fig.tight_layout()
    fig.show()
```

I get this error in Colab but I don't understand why. I can't find an answer to fix this error. What am I doing wrong? Did I have to define or import Dict before?

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-f10bf0f6a20c> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Function to plot the loss and metric during each training epoch.
----> 2 def loss_metric_curve_plot(model_results:Dict[str,List[float]]):
      3 
      4     train_loss = model_results["train_loss"]
      5     valid_loss = model_results["valid_loss"]

NameError: name 'Dict' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error because Python doesn't recognize `Dict` and `List` as types by default; they are part of the `typing` module, which provides support for type hints. To use `Dict` and `List` in your function annotations, you need to import them from the `typing` module. Add the following imports in your code.

```py
from typing import Dict, List
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def loss_metric_curve_plot(model_results: Dict[str, List[float]]):
    # Your function implementation...
```

By adding the import statement `from typing import Dict, List`, you make `Dict` and `List` available in your function's scope, which should resolve the `NameError` that you're getting.

Comment: Got it, problem solved. Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: In recent versions of Python you can also use the built-in types instead of the ones from `typing` in annotations, e.g. `dict[str, list[float]]`